# Syntax to add a calendar event to a specific outlook calendar?

Tags: macos, outlook, calendar, applescript

I have 2 calendars in my outlook app- each associated with different email accounts. One is an exchange account, and the other is IMAP.

I'm trying to write applescript that adds an event to the exchange account, but can't figure out the correct syntax.

```
set theStartDate to (current date)
set theEndDate to (current date)

set theTask to display dialog "Description of Task?" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
set theTask to (text returned of theTask)

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    
    set theAccount to the exchange account 1
    set theCategory to category "Task"
    
    set newAppt to make new calendar event with properties {account:theAccount, subject:theTask, start time:theStartDate, end time:theEndDate, has reminder:true, all day flag:true, free busy status:free}
end tell
```

This of course throws the error "error "Microsoft Outlook got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000"

I've read and tried syntax from about 20 different other stackexchange posts, but i can't figure it out :(

Can someone please advise? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a reference to a calendar - that's all it was.

```
set theStartDate to (current date)
set theEndDate to (current date)


set theTask to display dialog "Description of Task?" default answer "" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK"
set theTask to (text returned of theTask)

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    tell calendar 2
        set newAppt to make new calendar event with properties {subject:theTask, start time:theStartDate, end time:theEndDate, has reminder:true, all day flag:true, free busy status:free}
    end tell
end tell
```